# AlertDialog.Builder setMessage in the text to wrap

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.update_dialog_tittle));
    builder.setMessage(updateInfo.getDescription());
    builder.setCancelable(false);
```

updateinfo is javabean，Is obtained by reading the site XML,The website XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><updateInfo><version>1.2</version><url>http://localhost:8080/test.apk</url><description>update\n1:test\n2:test\n3test\n4:test</description></updateInfo>
```

The text to display shows the "update \n1: test \n2: test \n3 test \n4: test", \n display, no wrapping effect

Comment: What do you mean exactly? If you want to parse the `xml` data, you need to read [SAX](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xml/sax/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Give a try**
if your XML replaces `\n` with `<br>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"><updateInfo><version>1.2</version><url>http://localhost:8080/test.apk</url><description>update<br>1:test<br>2:test<br>3:test<br>4:test</description></updateInfo></p> <br>
```

You can try like this

```
builder.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(updateInfo.getDescription());
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much!!The use of <br> requires the use of CDATA components in XML